# Using "DIY" quality product images on website

Tags: attracting-clients

I'm not 100% sure this is the correct place to ask this but I guess I'll find out.

I am trying to startup up my own and my first business. Its a webshop which sells 3D prints. I offer both physical  products and a service to print anything they want. So they deliver a file to me and ill print it and ship it.

The problem that I have is that I am setting up a web shop, I need photo's of my prints for the web shop. I have bought a nice camera and made a makeshift photobooth. The picture quality is nice but it does look DIY-ish. As in the photobooth is clearly a makeshift one. 
Is this good enough for a local company to have or is a perfect image quality really necessary? I do not want to look unprofessional.

Just to make it a little bit more clear, the image quality of the camera is good. But the content of the image looks DIYish.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, and highly depends on your targeted customer *(I´d say in the maker-scene a "diy-look" could actually be a pro)*. Can you reword the question to define a specific goal we can address?

Comment: @Daniel Im planning on selling mostly gifts and cool toys etc. I ordered a nice photobooth ish thing today so Ill see if I can make some better pictures anyway.

Comment: You can also do a lot in post-processing. Invest some time to learn about filters in GIMP or Photoshop. Still, if you ask *How to make a better impression* instead of *is this good* you may get some pointers. Have a look in the graphics-stack also

Comment: @Daniel I invested in a nice photobooth kit, which came with 2 spot lights and 4 different colors of backdrops. The pictures already look better and ill try to edit the pictures in photoshop :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about image quality, it might be a good business investment to look around for someone with some experience with image editing - a design or photography student or professional.

You may not need such a person to take new photos, but they may have a better skill set where post processing the images is concerned, making them look better overall without reshooting.

I realize cost may be a factor, but if you yourself are concerned about the images, anyone else is going to see what you see times 10.

It all ultimately comes down to what you are willing to invest in this startup.

You *might* be able to find some quick tips for image editing by searching the web for specific problems (image to dark/light, remove background, etc). But really only a trained eye is going to do a good job.

---

Whether or not image quality alters the return on the site... well... you'd have to test that. There's no way to know otherwise.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the great reponse! ill see what I can accomplish with some photoshop or lightroom :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option for your web store is to purchase one or 2 stock photographs from one of the better stock sites and create samples from them. Including pro photos with your "diy" photos will show the range of what your output will look like.

If you don't want to buy stock photography, find a local photographer or 2 and partner with them. They'll be shooting weddings and other things, and could "upsell" your services to their clients.

Comment: I have mutliple photographer near me and ill have a talk with them. Thank you :)